# How to extend the object for the single java class present inside a jar using xsd?

Tags: java, xml, jar, xsd

I have many java class present inside a jar. I need to extend an object to the single java class present in the jar. I tried the below code

```
"<jxb:class name="paymentTransferDTO" superClass= "com.citigroup.ebusiness.jfp.global.support.TransferObject"/>"
```

But this extend the object to all the class present inside the jar. How to extend the object for the single java class present inside a jar?

In xsd file I have added these code. But this extends the TransferObject to all the java class present inside the jar!

Comment: <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
           <jaxb:globalBindings >
           <xjc:superClass name="com.citigroup.ebusiness.jfp.global.support.TransferObject"/>
           <xjc:serializable/>
            </jaxb:globalBindings>       
        </xs:appinfo>
     </xs:annotation>

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your transformation should look like some thing below (if you want to be specific)

```
<xs:complexType name="ChildClass">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="BaseClass">
      <!-- CONTENTS -->
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

**EDIT**

this example is posted before he edit the question to include his code

Answer (score 0):

In xsd file I have added these code. But this extends the TransferObject to all the java class

I need to extend only to the below mentioned java class:

.
      .
      .
      .